# flutter: "AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java line 511"

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In firebase, I see my apps crash.

Below are error data from Crashytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
stack size 8MB
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder$ReflectionAccessors.getChildId (AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:511)
io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder$ReflectionAccessors.access$500 (AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:411)
io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder.addChildrenToFlutterNode (AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:172)
io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder.convertToFlutterNode (AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:143)
io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder.getRootNode (AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:89)
io.flutter.view.AccessibilityBridge.createAccessibilityNodeInfo (AccessibilityBridge.java:510)
android.view.View.populateVirtualStructure (View.java:8656)
android.view.View.populateVirtualStructure (View.java:8659)
android.view.View.populateVirtualStructure (View.java:8659)
android.view.View.populateVirtualStructure (View.java:8659)
android.view.View.populateVirtualStructure (View.java:8659)
android.view.View.populateVirtualStructure (View.java:8659)
android.view.View.populateVirtualStructure (View.java:8659)
android.view.View.populateVirtualStructure (View.java:8659)
android.view.View.populateVirtualStructure (View.java:8659)
android.view.View.populateVirtualStructure (View.java:8659)
android.view.View.populateVirtualStructure (View.java:8659)
android.view.View.onProvideVirtualStructureCompat (View.java:8077)
android.view.View.onProvideVirtualStructure (View.java:8058)
android.view.View.dispatchProvideStructureForAssistOrAutofill (View.java:8724)
android.view.View.dispatchProvideStructure (View.java:8671)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideStructure (ViewGroup.java:3550)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideStructure (ViewGroup.java:3550)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideStructure (ViewGroup.java:3550)
android.app.assist.AssistStructure$WindowNode.<init> (AssistStructure.java:519)
android.app.assist.AssistStructure.<init> (AssistStructure.java:2047)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleRequestAssistContextExtras (ActivityThread.java:3311)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1872)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6898)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:537)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This error seems related to View / Widget, but I don't know which one is causing the error.
any idea what the above error about?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and as I understand so far it is related to the Google ads - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43575 but still no answer about the issue.